# Why Height 100% sometimes doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see I have 2 elements. Both of them have height 100% but one works and the other doesn't. **Why?**

Also, does anyone know how to put a background image in `imageZone` saying Preview here or an icon?

```css
.dropzone {
  border: 2px dashed #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 120px 60px 60px 60px;
}

.dropzone span {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.dropzone.dragover {
  border-color: #000;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #eeeeee5c;
}

.dropzoneUser {
  padding: 60px !important;
}

.imageZone {
  border: 2px dashed #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Upload avatar <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Upload an avatar image for this user." class="fa fa-question-circle help-label"></span></label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="dropzone dropzoneUser" id="dropzone">
        <span class="uploadIcon fa fa-upload"></span><br><br>
        <input type="file" name="fileUpload" accept="image/*" id="fileUpload" class="hide">
        <label for="fileUpload" id="uploadLabel" class="uploadLabel">Choose a file</label>
        <span>or drag & drop here</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img id="previewImage" class="imageZone">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `height:100%` means 100% of the parent height so if no height set to parent container it won't work ... and none of them are working, the first one is simply expading to content height

Comment: @TemaniAfif can you explain me how should I do this?

Comment: to do what ? what you need to have ... simply ask yourself : 100% of what ?

Comment: if you make it full page there's a big problem here. If I put a big image. it will expand the row size. I want to make sure the size stays the same.

Comment: I just want to make them the same size. Should I use a fixed height in pixel?